# CP037 encoding in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, encoding, java-me

As [CP037 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037) is not supported by BlackBerry by default does anyone know if there is any ready made libaray that I would be able to use? I've had a look online and I can't seem to see anything. Is the only option to write one myself? Does anyone have any tips on how to do such a thing?

Comment: Why do you need to use EBCDIC?

Comment: It is a client/server application I am working on. The server requires some text to be encoded using it. Changing the server code is going to be very difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing your own bytes -> String decoder seems pretty straightforward, as the encoding has no more than 256 characters.  Just turn the [table from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037) into a switch statement, and accumulate the resulting characters into a String.

```
byte[] rawCP037data = getEbcdicDatabytes();
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for(int i = 0; i < rawCP037data.length; i++) {
    buf.append(convertCP037toUnicodeChar(rawCP037data[i]));
}
String decodedString = buf.toString();

char convertCP037toChar(byte b) {
    switch (b) {
    case 0x99:
      return 'r';
    case 0xAB:  // upside down question mark
      return 0x00BF;
    // TODO! fill out the rest of the table here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I need is to be able to get the raw cp037 data, something like getEbcdicBytes method in your code. Would the same idea work? Just use a switch statement to convert the byte to its Cp037 equivalent?

Comment: Oh, so you want to go the other direction?  Take a Java string and convert it to CP037?  You should be able to iterate over the characters in a string and map from character to bytes, going the opposite direction of what I've written.  You may read a character that can't be represented by CP037, in which case you'll have to decide what the right behavior is for your application - commonly either replace it with some 'unknown' character, or throw an exception for invalid input.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I found this as well which might be useful for anyone having to do the same thing - http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/EBCDIC/CP037.TXT